Nanny tries to drown girl / Killer calls mom, kills daughter, then tries to kill mom
First movie, from what I remember was like a Lifetime type movie. It had a nanny who kept trying to drown a little girl. I believe the nanny killed the other sibling somehow and kept trying to get into the room to get the little girl to drown her in the bath tub.
Second Movie, a killer called the girls mom and was on the phone when he killed her daughter. The mother was in the car with the girls younger sister when she received the call. She was stuck in traffic and she got out of the car screaming. At the end of the movie the killer thinks the mom is in the shower but the mom is tricking him.. that's all I can remember. 
Also, these are not recent movies, probably at least 10+ years old.

Split the question into two different questions for first movie and second movie respectively, otherwise this question holds the chance for closing !

Is the second movie supposed to be a sequal to the first? If not, please do as Mistu4u suggested and split the question in-two.

Were they in English?  Do you know roughly which country they were set in?

The first movie sounds exactly like the awesome Bette Davis film The Nanny.
This is the synopsis of the movie (taken from IMDB):

Bette Davis is an English nanny whose charge is 10-year-old Joey, just
  released from a home for disturbed children where he'd spent two years
  undergoing treatment for drowning his little sister in the bath.
  Shortly after his arrival home, suspicion arouses again when his
  mother is poisoned. But Joey continues to insist Nanny is responsible,
  just as she was with the death of his little sister, with only a
  neighboring friend believing the young boy.

Okay, so the second movie sounds very like Eye for an Eye. It's about a woman who overhears her daughter's brutal rape and murder on the phone, and has some scenes similar to what you describe. From RogerEbert.com:

The movie stars Sally Field as Karen, a mother whose teenage daughter
  is raped and killed, in a particularly horrifying scene, early in the
  movie. The daughter calls for help, and Karen actually hears the
  attack over the telephone - and then tries to race home, gets stuck in
  traffic and is trapped in a nightmare scene where other drivers refuse
  her request to use a mobile phone.`

The Wikipedia page for the film describes the ending:

Karen sets a trap to lure Doob into her home, so that she can say
  killing him was self-defense. It works. After she shoots Doob dead and
  calls the police. Denillo arrives and tells Karen that he knows the
  truth and that she hasn't fooled him, to which she replies "prove it".
  He decides to tell his colleague that it was a "clear case of
  self-defense". When her husband arrives, he sits beside her, holding
  her hand, knowing what she has done.

Based on your descriptions, these two films sound most likely. So in summary:

Nanny Tries to Drown Girl: The Nanny
Killer calls mom, kills daughter, then tries to kill mom: Eye for an Eye

